How to compile a part of .tex file without commenting out the unwanted sections, to preserve cross-references?
I have my main.tex file which has the main text and sup.tex file which has the supplementary text, in the same project folder in LaTeX (I use overleaf). See the content of main.tex below, which gives all the content in main.tex and in sup.tex in the compiled PDF.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{upgreek}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\linespread{1.0} 
% landscape table
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\noindent\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

%my main text content goes here.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib}

\clearpage 

\input{sup.tex}



\end{document}

However I need to compile only the content in main.tex. I have referred to tables, figures etc. from the sup.tex in my main.tex. Therefore, I need to include sup.tex so that the cross-referencing information is available, but I don't want the content of sup.tex to appear in the compiled PDF.
How can I do this?
My failed attempt:
By referring to a previous response here according to what I understood, I did the following, but it does not properly add cross-references, and there-by throws out errors.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{upgreek}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\linespread{1.0} 
% landscape table
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\noindent\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
\end{filecontents*}

\includeonly{main}

\begin{document}

%my main text content goes here.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bib}

\clearpage 

\include{sup.tex}



\end{document}


Assuming the contents of sup.tex come at the end of the document, can you just delete the pages in question from the pdf file?

Thanks for the comment. I need to upload the .zip file of the entire project to the journal portal, so that it compiles it as a pdf. Therefore, deleting isn't the solution.

In that case, you should really consider creating a version of main.tex-- called, say, main2.tex -- that removes all cross-references to items not contained in the document that will be published in the journal. If you feel strongly that you should inform your readers that you've written a piece with additional  results, you can create a footnote near the start of the document to mention that a longer version of the document, with supplemental material, exists and may be obtained from you upon request.

I think you misunderstood the linked solution. blindtext just provides dummy text to illustrate the answer, and filecontents* serves to generate the files needed in the answer (they're not part of the solution). In your case, you need a master file, say master.tex which sets the document class and loads the packages, and contains \include{main}, include{sup} and \includeonly{main}. Note that you must first compile with the \includeonly line commented to generate the references, as explained in the linked answer.

Maybe the question How to cross-reference another document may also help you.

Thanks, @jlab
Instead of \include{...}, is there any other alternative method? Because, even if I do that, when uploaded into the journal's portal, it doesn't have a chance to first create the .aux file and then comment the \includeonly part, so it does not properly compile there.

Precise information about the process of building/compiling the document might be useful. Probably creating two documents, one with sub.tex, one without sub.tex, and in the one without sub.tex using xr/xr-hyper for attempting to cross-reference stuff occurring in the one with sub.tex is an option. Probably shellesc/write18 can be used to launch another compilation via latexmk where the presence of .aux-files is checked and \includeonly is used. Probably shellesc/write18 can be used to launch another compilation with different jobname and forking inclusion of sup.tex depending on the jobname.
